# How can I add hyperlinks to my v-data-table component's Application column?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, datatable, href, vuetify.js

The data table is loaded from database and I have the links there, as well as the name of the Applications. I do not want to show the links, just when I click on the Application name, it should open the matching link.

```
    headers: [
      {
        text: 'Name',
        left: true,
        value: 'CustomerFullName',
      },
      { text: 'Application Name', value: 'ApplicationName' },
      { text: 'Country', value: 'CustomerCountryCode' },
      { text: 'Email Adress', value: 'CustomerEmailAddress' },
      { text: 'Status', value: 'NewStatus'},
      { text: 'CB Status', value: 'CBStatusID' },
      { text: 'Trial ending', value: 'FormattedTrialEndsAt' },
      { text: 'Next billing at', value: 'FormattedCBNextBillingAt'},
      { text: 'User Limit', value: 'UserLimit' },
      { text: 'QuickBooks', value: 'QBEnabled' },
      { text: 'Wizard', value: 'NewWizardStatus'}
    ],



    <td v-for="(header, index) in headers" :key="index"
        :class="[ index === 0? 'text-xs-left': 'text-xs-center', 'body-2', 'ma-0', 'pa-0', 'pl-2']" v-if="header.value!==''">
      {{renderData(props.item, header)}}
    </td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<td v-for="(header, index) in headers" :key="index"
        :class="[ index === 0? 'text-xs-left': 'text-xs-center', 'body-2', 'ma-0', 'pa-0', 'pl-2']" v-if="header.value!==''">
<a :href="header.link">
      {{renderData(props.item, header)}}
</a>
    </td>
```

assuming that header object have link attribute.

Comment: It doesnt have yet, but even if it has I have to pass data to it somehow. Whats more, I only want to have link in a specific column, not in all.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass template tag for the specific header name (column name).

```
<v-data-table
          :headers="headers"
          class="elevation-1">
  <template v-slot:item.data.dataName="{ item }">
    <a :href="'mydata/'+ item.data.dataId" target="_blank">
      {{ item.data.dataName }}
    </a>
  </template>
</v-data-table>
```

Comment: Can you be more specific on this one? Where does item come from? thanks!